# Is there a way to test apps in different environments online

Tags: mobile-application, tablet, smartphone

As a UX designer, I like to test apps on different platforms and different devices. I can do this on my iPhone, Android 7" tablet, and soon, Nexus 5. But I'd like to test this a lot on iPad (which to date I still haven't got). I was wondering if there exists a sort of online tool to test apps in all those different environments or if it's really only possible to do this via the various devices?

Answer (score 2):

I have been using something called BrowserStack for a couple of weeks now:

http://www.browserstack.com/

You have to pay for it, but you can get a 3 month free trial via this microsoft site: http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

It has some emulators for mobile devices that you can use (including iOS), and also has a feature that allows you to see a screenshot of any given page in a wide range of devices. It is great for checking your site design isn't broken in different devices, but not so good for seeing how usable it is.

You could also see if there is a device testing lab near you:

http://opendevicelab.com/

which would allow you to physically test on a range of devices for free.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to benb's suggestions, there is also a service called [AppThwack](https://appthwack.com/) that lets you remotely test on hundreds of real mobile devices.

Comment: the thing is, i'd like to see how apps react and differ on iOS and Android (following iOS and Android's own design guidelines). When i use an emulator it actually shows me the website version of those apps (like Twitter), not the app-version, because it still detects that I'm viewing this on a desktop. So i would like to see the native app-versions on different platforms through a browser, if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just [emulate devices in the default Google Chrome from the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=ja) tab setting the viewport and user agents for whatever you wish to test in without the need of any 3rd party tools (for which there are lots).